# What does the term "coercion" mean in the context of Cognitive Linguistics?

Tags: terminology, cognitive-linguistics

I recently read a question that referred to "aspectual coercion" and looked up a paper called "[Aspectual coercion and the typology of change of state predicates](http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/andrewkg/akg-jl2007.pdf)".

To read this paper, I'll have to know, among other things, what "coercion" means in this context. The [relevant article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercion_%28linguistics%29) in Wikipedia was a stub that cited no references or links to other articles.

Hence the title question: What does the term "coercion" mean in the context of Cognitive Linguistics?

Comment: It is explained in the paper itself- in section 4.1.2. - very clearly.

Comment: Roger that.  Can you provide some examples of coercion in English?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll use an example from Bary's 2009 paper.

The Progressive in English doesn't go well with stative verbs (due to their semantic incompatibility):

*John is tall.* =>**John is being tall.*

On the other hand, we have:

*John is funny.* =>*John is being funny.*

Here, the mismatch is resolved by the progressive operator coercing (reinterpreting) a stative verb into eventive. "John is being funny" means "John is acting funny". It's no longer a state.